# ModuleNotFoundError after using pip3 install

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip, modulenotfounderror

recently, I've been learning Data Science on in visual studio code and all the modules I've been isntalling keep giving the ModuleNotFoundError when I try to use it.

I've tried installing them in the visual studio code terminal as well as the terminal inside my mac. This is the command I use
`python3 -m pip3 install scikit-learn`

^ I used all kinds of possible configurations such as using pip instead of pip3 and even trying to download sklearn cuz i thought it was a separate thing I had to get.

I've also looked at other stack overflow questions.

Most recently I'm trying to use scikit-learn module which includes sklearn

here is the import part of my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression #finds correlation between data and a trend line
from sklearn import metrics
import pandas as pd
import math
```

This is the error I get:
`"/Users/ethancha/Downloads/Data Science club/scikit.py" Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/ethancha/Downloads/Data Science club/scikit.py", line 7, in <module> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'`

From another stack overflow question I tried adding this at the top of my code:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, r"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages")
sys.executable
```

This just gives a new error(I copied the file path of where it was stored according to the forum).

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ethancha/Downloads/Data Science club/scikit.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from . import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    raise_build_error(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 31, in raise_build_error
    raise ImportError("""%s
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build:
__init__.py               __pycache__               _check_build.cpython-312-darwin.so
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

How do I use these modules without these problems?

Comment: you will need to check which interpreter vscode is using? is there a virtual environment in use? you can find that by clicking the version in the bottom right corner of vscode.

alternatively, try to run from the command line using `python3 <filename>.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try to work on python virtual env

you need to create a python virtual env and activate this

```
python -m venv venv
```

you have a folder named `venv`. Now run this command

```
./venv/Scripts/activate
```

and now install sklearn

```
python3 -m pip3 install scikit-learn
```

you can also select the virtual env in visual studio code.
Just press `ctrl` + `shift` + `p` and search `Select Interpreter` and select the local env and run the `ipython` and `jupyter-notebook` shell or run the python file.